# Select a random position in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, brute-force

Is there a way to select a random position in a 2d array of bools (bool[,]) with a negative value without bruteforcing?

Comment: What do you count as "brute force" in this case?

Comment: @Jon I would *guess* that means: keep picking points until a `false` is found (let's hope there is at least one)

Comment: doing random until a position in the two dimensional array with the negative value is found.

Comment: @Max0999 One solution would be to select a random cell in the array, set its value to `false`, and then return it's value. I appreciate this is a particularly absurd algorithm, but since it will answer your question perfectly, I would suggest you clarify what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a non-brute-force method, but it involves an initial scan of the entire table:

```
int[] negOffsets = new int[data.Length];
int dataOffset = 0, count = 0;
foreach(bool x in data)
{
    if(!x) negOffsets[count++] = dataOffset;
    dataOffset++;
}
if(count == 0) {
    // nothing to pick
} else {
    int index = negOffsets[rand.Next(0, count)];

    int x = index / data.GetLength(1),
        y = index % data.GetLength(0);
    // assertion: the following should be false
    bool b = data[x, y];
}
```

Also, you'd probably want to keep `offsets` around and re-use it between iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you will get the idea from the code. Obviously it requires some tunning, however the concept is to use TestClass as a cover for array. Does not require any scans and its quite easy to use ;)

```
 public class TestClass
    {
        public bool[,] BoolArray
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        private List<Tuple<int, int>> negativeValues;

        public TestClass(int x, int y)
        {
            this.negativeValues = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
            this.BoolArray = new bool[x, y];
        }

        public Tuple<int, int> GetPosition()
        {
            if (this.negativeValues.Count > 0)
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                return this.negativeValues[rand.Next(this.negativeValues.Count - 1)];
            }
            else
                return null;
        }



        public bool this[int x, int y]
        {
            get
            {
                return this.BoolArray[x, y];
            }

            set
            {
                if (!value)
                    negativeValues.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(x, y));

                this.BoolArray[x][y] = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Be sure to remove them though whenever a previously `false` entry is set to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's perfectly possible:

```
var random = new Random();
int xBound = 100;
int yBound = 100;
var values = new bool[xBound, yBound];

// Fill the values array
for (int y = 0; y < yBound; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < xBound; x++)
    {
        values[x, y] = random.Next(0, 2) == 1;
    }
}

// Find the value at a random position that's false
bool foundFalse = false;
int probeX, probeY;

while (!foundFalse)
{
    probeX = random.Next(0, xBound);
    probeY = random.Next(0, yBound);

    if (values[probeX, probeY] == false)
    {
        // Do something with your probeX, probeY values perhaps
        foundFalse = true;
    }
}
```

Hoewever, it's probably wise to ask whether this is useful or not. Why do you want to be probing randomly around in a multidimensional array until you find a certain value? Isn't there some underlying problem that can be solved differently, and more important, more efficiently?

Note, for example, that using this method it's perfectly possible for the `while()` loop to never finish.

You could try to loop through the array on beforehand, to locate the [x,y] indices on which a `false` is present and store those coordinates in a separate list of, for example, `Tuple<int,int>` (or use the more elegant solution posted by @MarcGravell).

Then you can select a random item from that list, and you'll have a random `[x,y]` where `values[x,y]` will be `false`.

Comment: That's exactly what I DONT want, I don't want any probing/bruteforcing to be involved in finding the value.

Comment: @Max0999 then explain youself better. What **do** you want to do? If you simply select one random X and Y and take a look at the values array on those indices, it's possible you'll find a `true` instead of the `false` you want to find. Then what?

Comment: I want to select a random probeX,probeY from the array, where the value is false, without having the possibility of reading from the array more times than the size of the array (which is what necessary)

Comment: @Max0999 I think you think there's some magic involved somewhere. You cannot know on what indices the array contains a `false` value, unless you walk over all indices at least once (given the contents of the array doesn't change), or indeed save them as soon as they're set as neurotix explains in another answer.